# Next JS add async attribute for generates a list of script files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, next.js

**We are using nextJs application. We need to apply async for all existing script tags. I have tried a lot. any once can help me on this.**

```
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1634913314210"></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1634913314210"></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1634913314210"></script>
```

after modification

```
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1634913314210" async></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1634913314210" async></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1634913314210" async></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running **NextJS v10.2.1 or newer**, you can tell NextJS to render these resources with `defer` instead of `async` by setting the following flag in your `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: { disableOptimizedLoading: true },
}
```

Note that this will only disable `async` tags for production builds, not development builds. Moreover, it also changes some other mechanisms related to script loading.

For more details, check out the implementation of [_document.tsx getScripts](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/pages/_document.tsx#L126), which exposes this method as a [`NextScript` component](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/pages/_document.tsx#L775). If you want to have more fine-grained control over these script tags, you can provide your own implementation of the `getScripts` method by implementing your own version of `NextScript`.

Below is an example I pulled from [this relevant issue on the NextJS GitHub project](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11120). You may also want to read into that thread a little bit to better understand how `async` works in this context.

```
class DeferredNextScript extends NextScript {
  getScripts() {
    return super.getScripts().map(script => {
      return React.cloneElement(script, {
        key: script.props.src,
        defer: true,
        async: false,
      })
    })
  }
  getDynamicChunks() {
    return super.getDynamicChunks().map(script => {
      return React.cloneElement(script, {
        key: script.props.src,
        defer: true,
        async: false,
      })
    })
  }
}
```